# MOSS 2007 Pre-Populate SSO Credentials

Tags: .net, sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I'm looking to set a user's credentials for a particular webpart/application that utilizes the SSO database within Sharepoint.  Can someone point me to a code sample of how I might do this in .net?  The webpart/application typically stores the user's credentials upon the first use but I'd rather they not even be bothered with entering them at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your integrating an existing .net application into SharePoint.  If so, the following article should help you out:

SharePoint Single Sign-on:  [Part I](http://www.joesharepoint.com/?p=7), [Part II](http://www.joesharepoint.com/?p=4)

Also, if your looking to integrate SharePoint into an existing log-in system, you can [implement a pluggable SSO Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms566925%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to do that for you.  You can also integrate SharePoint and active directory ([SO Question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307684/authenticate-sharepoint-with-active-directory)).

Comment: Interesting links but does not really answer my question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I'm not sure what your trying to do exactly, so I gave you the best collection of things I know can be done.

Comment: I have a webpart installed that connects to a backend unix system using credentials that are stored in the SSO database.  The first time the user clicks on that webpart they are prompted for their unix credentials.  For new users, I would like to programmatically set their unix credentials ahead of time so they are not prompted.

Comment: Why can't you have the web part provide the credentials to the unix system for the logged in SharePoint user?  I think you may need to post another question with some code and details about what your trying to do.  I'm not sure how your connecting to the Unix service, so I can't tell you how you can pass information to it.

Comment: The WebPart is a pre-canned solution that I have no ability to edit.  The WebPart will ask the user for their (unix) credentials the first time it is used which is then stored in the SSO database for subsequent usage.  All I'm attempting to do is prevent the user from having to enter the credentials.  My thought was that there would an API I could call into to set these credentials ahead of time.